# Format data in Pandas for multi-level Sankey in Plotly: source and target columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-python, sankey-diagram

I have data on the sequence of courses taken by students and I would like to represent the flows between classes using a Sankey diagram. My data is in a Pandas dataframe in a long format, where each step that someone took has a row and the order of those steps is specified by a column `order`:

| student | course | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jerry | A | 1 |
| Jerry | B | 2 |
| Jerry | C | NaN |
| Jessy | C | 1 |
| Jessy | A | 2 |
| Jessy | B | 3 |
| Raphael | A | 1 |
| Raphael | C | 2 |
| Raphael | C | 3 |
| Raphael | B | 4 |
| Sally | A | 1 |
| Sally | B | 2 |
| Sally | C | NaN |

I pivoted this table to aggregate it into sequences with the count of each sequence:

| course1 | course2 | course3 | course4 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | End | End | 2 |
| A | C | C | B | 1 |
| C | A | B | End | 1 |

Note that I want to retain the `End` value, but if this causes problems, I am happy to abandon this and just have people stop at a step.

Building a Sankey in Plotly requires a data format with the source and target. Here is the example on the Plotly docs.

```
source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3],
target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2]
```

***I need to get my data into the format above, but for my entire dataframe.***

If I was dealing with a small dataset, like the toy one above, I could manually create this. However, I have a dataframe with thousands of rows and I have no idea how to do this **in Pandas**. It looks like some sort of window calculation, but I have no idea how to do it.

I am also kinda confused about how to create the coding scheme because my failed attempts create a viz that doesn't have a sequence of four courses.

Any help is much appreciated.

Toy data:

```py
student = ['Jerry','Jerry','Jerry','Jessy','Jessy','Jessy','Raphael','Raphael','Raphael','Raphael','Sally','Sally','Sally']
course = ['A','B','C','C','A','B','A','C','C','B','A','B','C']
order = [1,2,np.NaN,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,np.NaN]
df = pd.DataFrame({'student':student, 'course':course,'order':order})
```

Comment: I thought it was a new question, but what is different about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66285745/reformatting-dataset-for-sankey-in-pandas)?

Comment: @r-beginners: they are different questions that ask for different solutions.

Comment: Can you please explain what is different?

Comment: I suggest that you actually read the questions. Once you do, you'll see that they ask for different output tables.

Comment: Is it that 'End' has been added? Then just change it to `df.fillna('End',inplace=True)`.

Comment: No. If you read the question, you will see bold letters that specify the desired end result.       "Building a Sankey in Plotly requires a data format with the source and target. Here is the example on the Plotly docs.

source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3],
target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2]
I need to get my data into the format above, but for my entire dataframe."

Comment: Was it for Sankey diagrams? By the way, the previous question was about data tableting, is my answer acceptable?